# Coloring worksheet tabs when extracting multiple dataframes to Excel file (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two CV files, and on different conditions i'm merging chosen rows to create new dataframes that I want to put together into one excel file, but in different spreadsheats. I'm storing newly created dataframes and titles in lists and I'm using such function to create XLSX file:

```
def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path,titles):
writer = ExcelWriter(xls_path)
for df,title in zip(list_dfs,titles):
    df.to_excel(writer,title)
writer.save()
save_xls(merged_tables,'Filename.xlsx',sheet_titles)
```

It works, i have many different sheets in one file, but also I'd like to color tabs of these spreadsheets, where last rows of certain columns (sum) aren't the same.

Comparison that i made :

```
merged_tables[0][merged_tables[0].columns[10]].iloc[-1] == merged_tables[0][merged_tables[0].columns[23]].iloc[-1]
```

Last row is sum, so if it's not located in the same row in both columns, i want to indicate it by coloring. This columns have the same name, so i'm accessing it by columns number. It returns me True or False.

As pandas on it's own doesn't offer formatting excel sheets, i have to use other library.

From xlsxwriter docs i've read that it's also possible to use this library as engine while writing to excel, and also openpyxl offers formatting, so i tried to go with it.

```
import openpyxl
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Filename.xlsx')
for i in wb2.worksheets:
    i.sheet_properties.tabColor ='FFFF00'
```

With this code i'm able to color all sheets, but i need to use condition here.

```
for n, (sheet,df) in enumerate(zip(wb2.worksheets,merged_tables)):
    try:
        if merged_tables[n][merged_tables[0].columns[10]].iloc[-1] == merged_tables[n][merged_tables[0].columns[23]].iloc[-1]:
            sheet.sheet_properties.tabColor ='FFFF00'
except ValueError:
    pass
```

I came up with something like this. I've added ValueError exception, as it may rise when number of rows are different, but i think that this code doesn't make sense at all and it does nothing.

So how should i do this? Maybe it would be better to find last row in openpyxl and don't use df's while looping through worksheets? Or maybe i shouldn't use openpyxl at all and maybe it will be possible to do with xlsxwriter as engine?